# Cypress Time out not respecting the value given on command

Tags: timeout, cypress

Since our test agents are slow some times- i am trying to add some additional time outs for some commands
I did it like using time out value on command as shown below.But its not respecting the value given 
My understanding is cypress will wait for "10000" MS for getting the #Addstory element?

Can any one advice is this is the correct way please?
Thank you so much

```
cy.get('#addstory > .ng-scope').click({ timeout: 10000 })
```

Comment: Also is there any way to change default time out for all requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I issue was i was adding time out on click not for getting the element when i changed like below -All good waiting for add story to be visible as i expected before click

```
 cy.get('#addstory > .ng-scope',{ timeout: 10000 }).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

In `cypress.json` file, increase the timeout to 10 seconds or what ever timeout you want like this: `"defaultCommandTimeout": 10000` and  save the file. Now close the app and open it again. Navigate to `Settings > Configuration` you should be able to see the new value set for defaultCommandTimeout.